# Pass multiple parameters to event handlers in React

Tags: reactjs, twitter-bootstrap-3

So im trying to make react work with ES6 syntax. In ES5 I had setInitialState without a constructor which worked with the function binding syntax. I have a list of prices which is arbitrary and I want the state to change when the input element is changed. But the right price has to be changed.

I'm not even quite sure this is the right way to do it. Can someone please tell me the most recent way this should be done?

Here is my code:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react'
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css';

export default class PriceTable extends Component {
  constructor(props, context) {
    super(props, context);

    this.state = {
      pid: this.props.pid || "12345",
      name: this.props.name || "name",
      prices: this.props.prices || [
        {count: 1, desc: 'one', price: 8.25},
        {count: 6, desc: 'six', price: 7.60},
        {count: 12, desc: 'twelve', price: 6.953}
      ]
    };

    this.setPid = this.setPid.bind(this);
    this.setName = this.setName.bind(this);
    this.setCount = this.setCount.bind(this, i);
    this.setDesc = this.setDesc.bind(this, i);
    this.setPrice = this.setPrice.bind(this, i);
    this.logDebug = this.logDebug.bind(this);
  }

  setPid(e) {
    this.setState({pid: e.target.value})
  }

  setName(e) {
    this.setState({name: e.target.value})
  }

  setCount(i, e) {
    var newPrices = this.state.prices
    newPrices[i].count = e.target.value
    this.setState({prices: newPrices})
  }

  setDesc(i, e) {
    var newPrices = this.state.prices
    newPrices[i].sec = e.target.value
    this.setState({prices: newPrices})
  }

  setPrice(i, e) {
    var newPrices = this.state.prices
    newPrices[i].price = e.target.value
    this.setState({prices: newPrices})
  }

  _renderPriceRow(price, i) {
    return (
      <tr key={i}>
        <td >
          <input type="text" className="form-control" defaultValue={price.count} onChange={this.setCount(this, i).bind(this, i)}/>
        </td>
        <td >
          <input type="text" className="form-control" defaultValue={price.desc} onChange={this.setDesc(this, i).bind(this, i)}/>
        </td>
        <td >
          <input type="text" className="form-control" defaultValue={price.price} onChange={this.setPrice(this, i).bind(this, i)}/>
        </td>
      </tr>
    );
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="row">
       ...
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

And this is the error...

```
PriceTable.jsx:21 Uncaught ReferenceError: i is not defined
    at new PriceTable (PriceTable.jsx:21)
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You are binding the functions incorrectly

In your constructor you need not specify the argument, you only need to bind it like `this.setDesc = this.setDesc.bind(this);`

Also In your onChange, when you want to pass paramters to the function you specify it with bind and not pass as arguments and bind them again .

```
onChange={this.setDesc.bind(this, i)}
```

You entire code will look like

```
import React, {Component} from 'react'
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css';

export default class PriceTable extends Component {
  constructor(props, context) {
    super(props, context);

    this.state = {
      pid: this.props.pid || "12345",
      name: this.props.name || "name",
      prices: this.props.prices || [
        {count: 1, desc: 'one', price: 8.25},
        {count: 6, desc: 'six', price: 7.60},
        {count: 12, desc: 'twelve', price: 6.953}
      ]
    };

    this.setPid = this.setPid.bind(this);
    this.setName = this.setName.bind(this);
    this.setCount = this.setCount.bind(this);
    this.setDesc = this.setDesc.bind(this);
    this.setPrice = this.setPrice.bind(this);
    this.logDebug = this.logDebug.bind(this);
    this._renderPriceRow = this._renderPriceRow.bind(this);
  }

  setPid(e) {
    this.setState({pid: e.target.value})
  }

  setName(e) {
    this.setState({name: e.target.value})
  }

  setCount(i, e) {
    var newPrices = this.state.prices
    newPrices[i].count = e.target.value
    this.setState({prices: newPrices})
  }

  setDesc(i, e) {
    var newPrices = this.state.prices
    newPrices[i].sec = e.target.value
    this.setState({prices: newPrices})
  }

  setPrice(i, e) {
    var newPrices = this.state.prices
    newPrices[i].price = e.target.value
    this.setState({prices: newPrices})
  }

  _renderPriceRow(price, i) {
    return (
      <tr key={i}>
        <td >
          <input type="text" className="form-control" defaultValue={price.count} onChange={this.setCount.bind(this, i)}/>
        </td>
        <td >
          <input type="text" className="form-control" defaultValue={price.desc} onChange={this.setDesc.bind(this, i)}/>
        </td>
        <td >
          <input type="text" className="form-control" defaultValue={price.price} onChange={this.setPrice.bind(this, i)}/>
        </td>
      </tr>
    );
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="row">
       ...
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

You could also make use of **[Arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)** to pass parameters like

```
onChange={(e) => this.setDesc(e,  i)}
```

Comment: This has actually the same effect as of not binding the function at all. I get the following error: ```Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'setCount' of undefined at _renderPriceRow ```

Comment: Thats because you haven't bind the renderPriceRow function. Check the update

Comment: Can you please briefly explain why I have to bind that function too? Is it because the function is out of scope of the actual class? This seems like a strange amount of boilerplate code here. Why is it not bound like in ES5 before?

Comment: You need to bind that function too because it uses `this` as a reference to call the `setCount` function and where `this` in the function refers to the context of the function itself if you don't bind it. much like binding other functions which use `setState`

Answer (score 2):

Use the `onChange` method like this:

```
onChange={this.setCount.bind(this, i)}
onChange={this.setDesc.bind(this, i)}
onChange={this.setPrice.bind(this, i)}
```

Remove these lines from `constructor`:

```
this.setCount = this.setCount.bind(this, i);
this.setDesc = this.setDesc.bind(this, i);
this.setPrice = this.setPrice.bind(this, i);
```

We can `bind` the `function` in `constructor`, where no extra parameter is required, like the these `functions` in your case:

```
this.setPid = this.setPid.bind(this);
this.setName = this.setName.bind(this);
this.logDebug = this.logDebug.bind(this);
```

But if in any `function` you want to pass any extra parameter, then you need to use either `arrow function` or `bind` that `function` by using `.bind(this, parameter)`.

**Note**:

Another thing that you need to change here is, the way you are updating the `state` values, You should never **mutate state variable directly**. When you assign an `array` to any variable, that variable will have the reference of that `array`, means whatever changes you will do to that variable will affect the original `array`.

So you need to create a copy of that variable and then do the changes on that and use `setState` to update the values.

As per [DOC](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#state):

> Never mutate this.state directly, as calling setState() afterwards may
>   replace the mutation you made. Treat this.state as if it were
>   immutable.

Comment: Ok I will do the copy stuff. Actually the lines you suggest to remove were my naive approch to fix the previous error: ```Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'setCount' of undefined at _renderPriceRow ```

Comment: no that not the way, whatever i suggested will work properly, i am sure about that, will provide a working code :)

Comment: becuas eyou didn't binded `_renderPriceRow` function.

Comment: write this line in the constructor: `this._renderPriceRow = this._renderPriceRow.bind(this);`