# Material UI Chip cross button / delete button not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, material-ui

I'm mapping Material UI Chips but I don't get cross button on them and neither I can click them or use onTouchTap event.

Here's the mapping

```
  {mapping.map(chipMap => {
          return (
            <div>
              <Chip
                key={chipMap._id}
                onRequestDelete={this.handleRequestDelete(chipMap)
                )}
                onTouchTap={this.handleTouchTap(chipMap)}
                style={styles.chip}
              >
                <Avatar src={chipMap.picture} />
                {chipMap.name}
              </Chip>
            </div>
          );
        })};
```

If i use `this.handleTouchTap(chipMap).bind(this)` then it gives undefined in console.

```
 handleRequestDelete = chipMap => {
    alert(chipMap.name);
  };

  handleTouchTap = chipMap => {
        alert(chipMap.name);
  };
```

I'm definitely sure the problem is with the this binding but I can't quite figure it out.

I also did this

```
 this.handleRequestDelete = this.handleRequestDelete.bind(this);
```

in constructor but to no avail.

The chips do get displayed along with accurate avatar picture and name but the close button doesn't gets displayed and I cant click on each Chip to even alert its name, id or picture

Comment: Possible duplicate of [React ES6 Syntax for binding multiple Parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43155329/react-es6-syntax-for-binding-multiple-parameters)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you are binding the method is not correct, you want to pass a extra parameter also in that so write it like this:

```
onRequestDelete={this.handleRequestDelete.bind(this,chipMap)}

handleRequestDelete(chipMap){
   console.log(chipMap);
}

onTouchTap={this.handleTouchTap.bind(this, chipMap)}

handleTouchTap(chipMap){
   console.log(chipMap);
}
```

As per [MDN DOC](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind):

```
syntax: fun.bind(thisArg[, arg1[, arg2[, ...]]])
```

> The bind() method creates a new function that, when called, has its
>   this keyword set to the provided value, with a given sequence of
>   arguments preceding any provided when the new function is called.

**First pass the thisArg:**

The value to be passed as the this parameter to the target function when the bound function is called.

**Then pass all the argument, arg1, arg2, ...:**

Arguments to prepend to arguments provided to the bound function when invoking the target function.

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH! Never would've figured it out on my own.