# Passing id with onClick function React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, babeljs

I am having problem with passing id to handleClick function and console.log'ing it into the console.
I have tried simple example which works but i can not understand why it doesn't work in my implementation.

Here is the code of working example:

```js
 var obiekt = [{"Zdjecie":"http://i.imgur.com/A83qNiV.jpg"},{"Zdjecie":"http://i.imgur.com/wwOoOIc.png"}];
class NavbarList extends React.Component {
 constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      text: "Old Text",
      id: 0,
   isPasswordPage : false,
      isUsernamePage : true
    };
    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
  }

  handleClick(event) {
    const {id} = event.target;
    console.log(id);

    this.setState({
       text: "New text",
       id: event.target.id,
    isPasswordPage : true,
      isUsernamePage : false
    
    });
 }
   passwordpage(){
    return(

        <div className="mainapp">
          <h2>{this.state.id}</h2>
          <div>
            {obiekt.map((obj, index) =>{
    if(index == this.state.id) return (
    <div  key = {index}>
    <img src= {obj.Zdjecie} alt=""  key = {index}></img>
    </div>
    )
  })}
          </div>
        </div>

    );
  };

  render() {
    var usernameComp = (
      <form>
        <div className="mainapp">
          <div>
   {obiekt.map((obj, index) => 
    <div onClick={this.handleClick}  id={index} key={index}>Next</div>
   )}
          </div>
        </div>
      </form>
    );
    
    return (
      <div>
        { this.state.isUsernamePage ? usernameComp : null }
        { this.state.isPasswordPage ? this.passwordpage() : null }
      </div>
    );
  }
}
  


ReactDOM.render(
  <NavbarList  />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Here is my code:

```js
<div id="root"></div>
    <script type="text/babel">
 const navbarValue = [{"Category":"Home"},{"Category":"Sport"},{"Category":"Technologia"}];
 var obiekt = [{"Zdjecie":"http://i.imgur.com/A83qNiV.jpg"},{"Zdjecie":"http://i.imgur.com/wwOoOIc.png"}];
class Strona extends React.Component {
 constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      id: 0,
      isArticleListPage : true,
     isArticlePage : false
    };
    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
  }
  handleClick(event) {
    const {id} = event.target;
    console.log(id);

    this.setState({
       id: event.target.id,
      isArticleListPage : false,
   isArticlePage : true
    
    });
 }
   articlepage(){
    return(
      <div>
    <div className="navbar-wrapper">
 <div className="container">
 <nav className="navbar navbar-fixed-static-top navbar-inverse">
 <div className="container">
 <div className="navbar-header">
 <button type="button" className="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
    <span className="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
  <span className="icon-bar"></span>
  <span className="icon-bar"></span>
  <span className="icon-bar"></span>
 </button>
 <a className="navbar-brand" href="">Back</a>
 </div>
 <div id="navbar" className="collapse navbar-collapse">
  <ul className="nav navbar-nav">
  {navbarValue.map((obj, index) => {
   if (index == this.state.id) 
   return <li className="active" key={index}><a   id={index} onClick={this.onClick}>{obj.Category}</a></li>
    return <li  key={index}><a  id={index} onClick={this.onClick}>{obj.Category} </a></li>
})}
</ul>
 </div>
 </div>
 </nav>
 </div>
 </div>
  <div className="container">
 <div id="carousel-example-generic" className="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" data-interval="3000">
 <div className="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
 <div className="item active">
   {obiekt.map((obj, index) =>{
    if(index == this.state.id) return <img src= {obj.Zdjecie} alt="" key= {index}/>
  })}
   <div className="container">
            <div className="carousel-caption">
              <h1>One more for good measure.</h1>
              <p className="lead">Less.</p>
              <a className="btn btn-large btn-primary" href="#">Browse gallery</a>
            </div>
          </div>
  </div>
 </div>
 </div>
  </div>
   </div>
    );
  };

  render() {
    var articlelistpage = (
       <div>
 <div className="navbar-wrapper">
 <div className="container">
 <nav className="navbar navbar-fixed-static-top navbar-inverse">
 <div className="container">
 <div className="navbar-header">
 <button type="button" className="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
    <span className="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
  <span className="icon-bar"></span>
  <span className="icon-bar"></span>
  <span className="icon-bar"></span>
 </button>
 <a className="navbar-brand" href="#">BrandName</a>
 </div>
 <div id="navbar" className="collapse navbar-collapse">
  <ul className="nav navbar-nav">
  {navbarValue.map((obj, index) => {
   if (index ==this.state.id) 
   return <li className="active" key={index}><a   id={index} onClick={this.onClick}>{obj.Category}</a></li>
    return <li  key={index}><a  id={index} onClick={this.onClick}>{obj.Category} </a></li>
})}
</ul>
 </div>
 </div>
 </nav>
 </div>
 </div>
 <div className="container">
 <div id="carousel-example-generic" className="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" data-interval="3000">
 <div className="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
 {obiekt.map((obj, index) => {
  if (!index) return (
  <div className="item active" key={index}>
  <img src={obj.Zdjecie} alt=""/>
   <div className="container">
            <div className="carousel-caption">
              <h1>One more for good measure.</h1>
              <p className="lead">Less.</p>
              <a className="btn btn-large btn-primary" href="#">Browse gallery</a>
            </div>
          </div>
  </div>
  )
  else return(
  <div className="item" key={index}>
  <img src={obj.Zdjecie} alt=""/>
   <div className="container">
            <div className="carousel-caption">
              <h1>One more for good measure.</h1>
              <p className="lead">Less.</p>
              <a className="btn btn-large btn-primary" href="#">Browse gallery</a>
            </div>
          </div>
  </div>
  )
  })}
 </div>
 <a className="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="prev">
      <span className="sr-only">Previous</span>
    </a>
    <a className="right carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="next">
      <span className="sr-only">Next</span>
    </a>
 </div>
  </div>
  <div className="container marketing">
 {obiekt.map((obj, index) =>{
 if(index % 2 == 0) return (
 <div onClick={this.handleClick}  id={index} key={index}>
  <hr className="featurette-divider" />
      <div className ="row featurette" >
      <div className="col-md-7">
      <h2 className="featurette-heading">First featurette heading. <span className="text-muted">It'll blow your mind.</span></h2>
      <p className="lead">Donec ullamcorper nulla non metus auctor fringilla. Vestibulum id ligula porta felis euismod semper. Praesent commodo cursus magna, vel scelerisque nisl consectetur. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo.</p>
       </div>
       <div className="col-md-5">
       <img className="featurette-image img-responsive center-block" src={obj.Zdjecie} alt="Generic placeholder image"/>
     </div>
    </div>
 </div>
 )
 else return (
 <div onClick={this.handleClick}  id={index} key={index}>
  <hr className="featurette-divider" />
      <div className ="row featurette" >
      <div className="col-md-7 col-md-push-5">
      <h2 className="featurette-heading">First featurette heading. <span className="text-muted">It'll blow your mind.</span></h2>
      <p className="lead">Donec ullamcorper nulla non metus auctor fringilla. Vestibulum id ligula porta felis euismod semper. Praesent commodo cursus magna, vel scelerisque nisl consectetur. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo.</p>
       </div>
       <div className="col-md-5 col-md-pull-7">
       <img className="featurette-image img-responsive center-block" src={obj.Zdjecie} alt="Generic placeholder image"/>
     </div>
    </div>
 </div>
 )
 })}
  </div>
   
 </div>
    );
    
    return (
      <div>
        { this.state.isArticleListPage ? articlelistpage : null }
        { this.state.isArticlePage ? this.articlepage() : null }
      </div>
    );
  }
}
  


ReactDOM.render(
  <Strona  />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

I had problems even in puting this code in the snipped.
Problem with the code is that i am not passing id from the those divs with ID:

```
<div onClick={this.handleClick}  id={index} key={index}>
</div>
```

to

```
handleClick(event) {
const {id} = event.target;
console.log(id);

this.setState({
   id: event.target.id,
  isArticleListPage : false,
  isArticlePage : true

});
}`
```

Error img [image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [React ES6 Syntax for binding multiple Parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43155329/react-es6-syntax-for-binding-multiple-parameters)

Comment: Nice, please provide solution then.

Comment: What do you mean, The answer on a duplicate question already provides you a way as to how you would pass id, `onClick={(e) => this.handleClick(e, index)}` and handleClick will be `handleClick(event, id) {

this.setState({
   id: event.target.id,
  isArticleListPage : false,
  isArticlePage : true

});`
}

Comment: Have you tried binding the function? `<div onClick={this.handleClick.bind(this)}  id={index} key={index}></div>`

Comment: I can not see console.log being run. :(

Comment: Actually, the thing is, when you click the div, it gives the clicked item in event.target instead of the div you want, that's why it's not giving the console of the id. May I know your needs?

Comment: I need handleClick to be run, make it change values as they are listed including id and then pass it to render with this.state.id

Comment: `<div id={index} onClick={(e) => this.handleClick(index,e)} />` `handleClick(id, event){console.log(id)}`

Comment: Thank you so much. You are my hero.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can try the following:

```
<div id={index} onClick={(e) => this.handleClick(index,e)} />
```

And override the function like this:

```
handleClick(id, event){console.log(id)}
```

You can find the fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/mzrezw2k/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there's a whoooole lot of unnecessary code in your question, try to make a nice concise example. I think what you mean is how to pass the id as an argument to the handle click function? It could be done using an arrow function.

```
<div id={index} onClick={() => this.handleClick(index)} />
```

Comment: I know and i am sorry but i did not made it any different from the working example and it doesn't want to work.

Comment: Try `<div id={index} onClick={(e) => this.handleClick(e)} />`.

Comment: Doesn't work, might be something with Babel library.

Comment: Yeah, it is not working i am getting no error but a highlight from babel.