# Delete function deleting wrong items

Tags: node.js, reactjs, redux

My delete button is working but not in the way I want it to. For example, I have 3 items and want to delete the first item. When I click the button the third item gets deleted. Then when I click it again the second item gets deleted. I'm trying to delete by the id but it's not doing that.

I'm using Redux so here is my action.

```
export const deleteBook = (id) => async (dispatch) => {
try {
    const res = await axios.delete(`/profile/books/${id}`);
    dispatch({
        type: GET_PROFILE,
        payload: res.data
    });
} catch (error) {
    dispatch({
        type: GET_ERRORS,
        payload: error.response.data
    });
  }
};
```

And my component

```
onDelete = (id) => {
    this.props.deleteBook(id);
};
<button onClick={this.onDelete}>Delete</button>
```

If I do `this.onDelete(book_id)` it deletes everything when the page refreshes.

Comment: in the code presented, Think about what `id` will contain. It certainly won't contain your book id. If you instead did `{this.onDelete(book_id)}`, it's going to call that function every time the page renders, thus deleting all of the books instantly. You need a mixture of the two.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Passing id with onClick function React](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45160579/passing-id-with-onclick-function-react)

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the above snippet of code the `onDelete` function will be receiving an event object and not the book id you are expecting.

You need to update your code to be something like this:

```
onDelete = (id) => () => {
    this.props.deleteBook(id);
};
<button onClick={this.onDelete(book_id)}>Delete</button>
```

Additionally you may have a rendering issue when you are listing your books, if you have not used a `key` prop react maybe not able to tell what instance of the book has been deleted.