# Warning: _renderNewRootComponent(): Render methods should be a pure function of props and state;

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, es6-class

I try to run a class Buttons, with passing a value to method visibilityFilter(value){...} and get the error

```
Warning: _renderNewRootComponent(): Render methods should be a pure function of props and state; 
triggering nested component updates from render is not allowed. 
If necessary, trigger nested updates in componentDidUpdate. 
Check the render method of Buttons.
```

My code is the following:

```
class Buttons extends React.Component {
    visibilityFilter(value){
        let action = {type: 'set_visibility_filter',payload: {name: value, on: true}};
        store.dispatch(action);
    };
    render(){           
        return(
            <div className="container-fluid">
                <div className="row">
                    <div className="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-0">
                        <buttom type="button" className="m-t-1-em w-100 btn btn-info" onClick={this.visibilityFilter('favorite')} >Favorite</buttom>
                    </div>
                </div>              
            </div>
        );
    };
};
```

What is the matter and how to pass a value to the method?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [React ES6 Syntax for binding multiple Parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43155329/react-es6-syntax-for-binding-multiple-parameters)

Answer (score 1):

You need to get rid of () after method in onClick=(...), use non standard html attributes and rewrite your code with the help of event object like this:

```
class Buttons extends React.Component {
    visibilityFilter(event){
        let action = {type: 'set_visibility_filter',
          payload: {name: event.target.dataset.filterName, on: true}};
        store.dispatch(action);
        console.info(' event.target.dataset.filterName:',
          event.target.dataset.filterName);
    };
    render(){           
        return(
            <div className="container-fluid">
                <div className="row">
                    <div className="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-0">
                        <buttom type="button" 
                          className="m-t-1-em w-100 btn btn-info"
                          onClick={this.visibilityFilter}
                          data-filter-name="favorite">
                          Favorite
                       </buttom>
                    </div>
                </div>              
            </div>
        );
    };
};
```

Hopefully it will help.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are invoking the visibilityFilter() function immediately.  The render() method is invoked then it calls the visibilityFilter() function which does a dispatch that changes state, which then causes a re-render.  Nothing in the render method should change your state.

Instead, the onClick should look like this.
`onClick={this.visibilityFilter.bind(this, 'favorite')}`.

You then can use the argument `favorite` in the click handler as the first parameter.