# onClick event handler

Tags: json, reactjs

I am trying to set an onClick event handler. I have a list of json 100 objects which is retrieved from an [API](http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts) using axios. Whole data is stored in a variable using .map(), when this list is rendered we get titles of all the object from [API](http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts). Now when I click any title I want the details of that object(see API for details). Here is my code for demo.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { Route, Link, withRouter } from 'react-router';
import axios from 'axios';

export default class FetchDemo extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      posts: []
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    axios.get(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts`)
      .then(res => {
        var data = res.data;
        const posts = data.map(obj => obj);
        this.setState({ posts });
        console.log(posts);
      });
  }

  handleClick(){
    console.log("Id:/*ID of clicked title*/ title: /*title of clicked title*/ userId: /*userId of clicked title*/ body: /*body of clicked title*/");
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <ul>
          {this.state.posts.map(post =>
            <li key={post.id} onClick={this.handleClick}><Link to="demo">{post.id} {post.title}</Link></li>
          )}
        </ul>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

I have used

```
<Link to="demo"></Link>
```

which points to same demo.js but that I did just to show a clickable link which wont leave the page.
the componentdidmount part gives me all the objects on that API. But I am unable to get the {id} {title} {userId} {body} on console. I also tried

```
handleClick(){
    console.log("Id: " + this.post.id+ "title: " +this.post.title+ "userId: "+this.post.userId+ "body: "+this.post.body);
  };
```

but didnt work. Where did I go wrong?

Comment: This wil help you, you need to pass at least the index of the row https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43155329/react-syntax-for-passing-multiple-parameters-to-onchange-onclick-functions/43155570#43155570 to be able to identify

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to bind your handler in the constructor.

```
constructor() {
  ...
  this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this)
}

handleClick(post) {
  console.log(post)
}
```

Comment: That was not too important. I am saying that coz even without binding the handleClick function was getting called. and on console I got "Id: title: userId: body:" but when I try doing "Id: " + this.post.id+ " title: userId: body:" I am getting error TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined

Comment: So then you need to bing the `post` object on it. `<li key={post.id} onClick={this.handleClick.bind(this, post)} .../>` and add `post` as argument to your method.

Comment: Yes, thanks I just did that and it worked just fine but what if I have to print the data on a new route instead of console (say jsondata.js). can u help me out with that?

Comment: In that case I'd send only the post `id` to this new route (as `newRoute/posts/${post.id}`)  and get the post back in the new route/component.

Comment: sorry what? For example
 `import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { Route, Link, withRouter } from 'react-router';
import axios from 'axios';
import FetchDemo from 'demo';

export default class JsonPH extends React.Component {

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <ul>
          {this.post.id}{this.post.title}{this.post.userId}{this.post.body}
        </ul>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
`
this is my new file jsondata.js now make changes here or in the previous file (demo.js) will u please? #mNoob

Comment: It's a bit hard to read code in the comment section, sorry. I suggest you close this question, accept the answer that have helped you with that and then open a new question so not only me but everyone else can help you.

Comment: I can understand. But I couldn't indent the code. Anyway just explain how to send only post Id to new route. I'll manage the rest

Answer (score 0):

You can pass arguments to the `handleClick` function. And also route to a specific route for that item.

**Example:**

```
  handleClick(post){
    const { id, title, userId, body } = post;
    console.log('Id: ', id, 'Title: ', title, 'userId: ', userId, 'Body: ', body);
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <ul>
          {this.state.posts.map(post =>
            <li key={post.id} onClick={this.handleClick.bind(this, post)}>
                <Link to=`demo/{$post.id}`>{post.id} {post.title}</Link>
            </li>
          )}
        </ul>
      </div>
    );
  }
```

Comment: Thanks Bro. It worked. I forgot to pass post. thanks a lot, again.

Comment: Hey @bennygenel what if I have to print the data on a new route instead of console (say jsondata.js). can u help me out with that?

Comment: Do you mean you need to pass data to another component? I didn't understand what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: yes exactly! to another component. So far I've been getting info on the console, but I want to send this data to a different component.

Comment: are you using any routing component?

Comment: M sry didnt get U. I m trying to send the clicked link data to a new component and render it on that component, if that's what u are asking

Comment: How do you handle navigation in your app? with [react-router](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/guides/philosophy)?

Comment: You don't have to. You have 2 basic options. One is that you can integrate [Redux](http://redux.js.org/docs/basics/UsageWithReact.html) or [Mobx](https://github.com/mobxjs/mobx-react) like state management in your app and read the required post from the store or you can just fetch the required data again from the server inside the next page with the Id you send with the path.

Comment: can U please extend the second way? More details would be great!

Comment: Check [this example](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/recursive-paths) from react-router documents. And please mark as answered your question if any of the answers solved your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of binding your function to your component, which obviously works as well, you can just declare your `handleClick()` like this: `handleClick = () => {...}`. This syntax makes use of `arrow` functions. There's a block post about `arrow` functions: https://medium.com/@machnicki/handle-events-in-react-with-arrow-functions-ede88184bbb

Answer (score 0):

On your LI element try:

```
onClick={this.handleClick.bind(this, post)}
```

And then in your "handleClick" method

```
handleClick(post) {
    console.log('clicked post', post);
}
```