# get Value of selected item in FlatList. -- React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, ecmascript-6

I have implemented a flat list component by binding an array. when i tap an item . I have to get either item name or Id.

```
 _renderList = ({ item }) => {
    return (
        <View style={styles.listContainer} onPress={this._selectedItem(item.text)}  >
            <Image style={styles.listImage} source={item.avatar} />
            <Text style={styles.listText} >{item.text}</Text>
            <Text style={styles.listVal} >{item.val}</Text>
            <Image style={styles.listImage}   source={require('../../resources/icons/MyAccount/arrowright.png')} />
        </View>
    );

}


<FlatList data={this.state.data} renderItem={this._renderList} />
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43155329/pass-multiple-parameters-to-onchange-onclick-functions-in-react/43155570#43155570

Comment: The error is `onPress={this._selectedItem(item.text)}  >` check the duplicate question

Comment: where is the duplicate question link?

Comment: In my comment above. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43155329/pass-multiple-parameters-to-onchange-onclick-functions-in-react/43155570#43155570

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Considering @SNT answer and bennygenel  comments. I have added this. answer as both of their suggestions requires attention.

```
 _renderList = ({ item }) => {
    return (
     <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={(event)=>this._selectedItem(item.text)}>
        <View style={styles.listContainer}>
            <Image style={styles.listImage} source={item.avatar} />
            <Text style={styles.listText} >{item.text}</Text>
            <Text style={styles.listVal} >{item.val}</Text>
            <Image style={styles.listImage}   source={require('../../resources/icons/MyAccount/arrowright.png')} />
        </View>
     </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
    );

}


<FlatList data={this.state.data} renderItem={this._renderList} />
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `TouchableOpacity`, `TouchableHighlitfor`, `TouchableWithoutFeedback` `onPress` event. `View` doesn't provide `onPress` prop.

```
 _renderList = ({ item }) => {
    return (
     <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={(item)=>this._selectedItem(item.text)}>
        <View style={styles.listContainer}>
            <Image style={styles.listImage} source={item.avatar} />
            <Text style={styles.listText} >{item.text}</Text>
            <Text style={styles.listVal} >{item.val}</Text>
            <Image style={styles.listImage}   source={require('../../resources/icons/MyAccount/arrowright.png')} />
        </View>
     </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
    );

}


<FlatList data={this.state.data} renderItem={this._renderList} />
```

Comment: `onPress={(item)=>this._selectedItem(item.text)}` should be `onPress={(event)=>this._selectedItem(item.text)}`

Comment: Its returning undefined in alert message  @SNT

Comment: which alert message? what is your _selectedItem function?